# Annihilate duplicate rows in a $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, I would like to remove duplicate rows from the matrix. Instead of implementing this algorithmically where each row must be checked against every subsequent row, I would like to try and take advantage of mathematical operations.

For instance in the matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
either the first or third row should be deleted (which one matters not).

Does anyone know of such a mathematical operation that can take $\mathbf{A}$ and multiply/divide/<operate> with either itself or another $n \times n$ matrix (or vector) such that duplicate rows are deleted (but one of the duplicates is kept)?

Comment: @Doug Unless I am missing something, the algorithm for removing duplicate rows is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$. In particular, I am interested in adjacency matrices so such an algorithm is not practical for graphs with millions of nodes. Furthermore, I am using a programming interface that is highly optimized for sparse matrix operations. So in practice (in my context), a single matrix operation would be far less computationally expensive than the naiive approach.

Comment: It would be interesting to know more about how this operation is useful in your adjacency matrices. As you know, if two rows are identical in the adjacency matrix of a graph, then the two corresponding nodes have exactly the same set of neighbors. If you pluck one of the two vertices out, you would need to remove its column as well if you intend on having an adjacency matrix afterwards.

Comment: @SammyBlack The final "adjacency" matrix represents the final step of the Markov Clustering algorithm. That is, rows with nonzero entries are "attractor" nodes and "attract" the indices (node) of the nonzero columns. You can see why having two identical rows means two attractors attract each other and the same nodes, so they are to be part of the same "cluster." So the final matrix is not exactly an adjacency matrix anymore, perhaps I should have given that context in the question. I suppose it is sort of beyond the scope of the initial question, though.